# Can't locate error in latex table

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\adjustbox{max width=1\textwidth}{
\small
\begin{tabular}{c|c|*{7}{c|}}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Variance ($\sigma^{2}$)} \tabularnewline
    \cline{2-9}
    \multirow{8}*{\rotatebox{90}{Mean ($\mu$)}} &
&    \bfseries 0 & \bfseries 2 & \bfseries 6 & \bfseries 10 & \bfseries 14 &\bfseries 18 & \bfseries 20 \tabularnewline
    \cline{2-10}
&    \bfseries 0 & 1682.183 & 1681.979 & 1681.759 & 1681.652 & 1681.620 & 1681.603 & 1681.595 \tabularnewline  
    \cline{2-10}
&    \bfseries 0.5 & 1693.820 & 1689.220 & 1682.688 & 1681.661 & 1681.622 & 1681.603 & 1681.595\tabularnewline 
    \cline{2-10}
&    \bfseries 2 & 1698.682 & 1695.159 & 1687.257 & 1682.034 & 1681.633 & 1681.604 & 1681.596 \tabularnewline 
    \cline{2-10}
&    \bfseries 5 & 1700.203 & 1697.297 & 1690.221 & 1683.147 & 1681.743 & 1681.608 & 1681.597 \tabularnewline 
    \cline{2-10}
&    \bfseries 8 & 1701.064 & 1698.618 & 1692.169 & 1684.388 & 1682.033 & 1681.616 & 1681.598 \tabularnewline 
    \cline{2-10}
&    \bfseries 12 &  1701.651 & 1699.463 & 1693.457 & 1685.524 & 1682.497 & 1681.668 & 1681.605  \tabularnewline 
    \cline{2-10}
&    \bfseries 15 & 1702.081 & 1699.804 & 1693.958 & 1686.039 & 1682.757 & 1681.710 & 1681.608 \tabularnewline 
    \cline{2-10}
  \end{tabular}
}
\label{table:errors}
\caption{a caption.}
\end{table}
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting an error on my table?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `{c|c|*{7}{c|}}` declares 9 columns but  `\cline{2-10}` uses column 10....

Comment: unrelated but `\label{table:errors}\caption{a caption.}` won't give an error message, but won't work, the label has to be after, or in, the `\caption`.

Comment: `\adjustbox{max width=1\textwidth}{` only scale tables as a last resort (and even then do not do it) it produces inconsistent font sizes and rule widths and a very distracting document as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{c|c|*{7}{c|}}
```

declares 9 columns but

```
\cline{2-10}
```

uses column 10.